# Ninja Forms date picker isn't working on WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins, datepicker, ninja-forms

I have a client who is using Ninja Forms and for whatever reason, I can select a date (any month) on the 1st through the 6th, but any date past then, it prompts the error "Please enter a valid date"

I've tried changing the date format, and I've ensured that he's using the latest version of the plugin.  I've deactivated it, reactivated it, and checked their FAQ / known issues and haven't found anything.

Any insight would be very helpful.  Thanks!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I feel you, but this is wordPress.  There's not a lot of code I can really show you.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it.  It turned out that (for whatever reason) the date format that had been working just decided not to.  I changed it and then it just worked.  None of the preset formats that come loaded with Ninja Forms would do it, so I decided to attempt others on the off-chance that it made a difference.

WordPress, am I right?

Comment: So what date format worked for you?

Comment: Oh gosh.  Looking back 4 months ago, I can't believe I didn't write down the solution.  I'll explain the process for you at least.  I went through each date format before one just worked.  You'll go through quite a few, but then it just worked.  Sorry I can't be more helpful, but I hope you figure it out.  <3